# How to make child as parent in xml tree

Tags: sql, xml, mq, messagebroker

I am working on message broker. But the query I am doing is very simple and can be answered by any DB guy also .

here is the query code to read xml and getting xml output

```
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.root.row[rowCnt].product_Info = THE (SELECT THE(SELECT C.*:Codes.*:Code AS TyrePatternCd FROM T.*:Classification[] AS C 
                    WHERE C.(XMLNSC.Attribute)Type = 'BRAND') AS product
                FROM itemMaster.*:ItemMasterHeader[] AS T );
```

This gives xml output like

```
<root name="Product">
 <row>
  <product_Info>
   <product>
    <TyrePatternCd>002</TyrePatternCd>
   </product>    
 </row>
</root>
```

How can I make it like

```
   <root name="Product">
     <row>
      <product_Info>
        <TyrePatternCd>002</TyrePatternCd>  
     </row>
    </root>
```

If I remove the `AS product` in query it makes `column` tag in tree.
How can I make child as parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SELECT ITEM to omit the 'product' element, and directly assign the result.

```
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.root.row[rowCnt].product_Info = THE (SELECT ITEM THE(SELECT C.*:Codes.*:Code AS TyrePatternCd FROM T.*:Classification[] AS C 
                    WHERE C.(XMLNSC.Attribute)Type = 'BRAND')
                FROM itemMaster.*:ItemMasterHeader[] AS T );
```